# Why isn't the flushed output from my Emacs shell buffer getting into the kill ring?

Tags: shell, yank, comint, kill-ring

Following the advice given on p. 121 of *Learning GNU Emacs*, 2nd Ed.,
I'm entering the command sequence: `C-c C-o`, immediately after executing a command in my Emacs *shell* buffer.
And I'm seeing the output from that command get flushed, as expected.

However, the flushed output is *not* making it into my kill ring.
When I move into another buffer and give the command: `C-y`, I don't get the flushed output.
Instead, I get the last thing I copied in Safari, using: `Cmd-C`.

I'm on a MacBook Pro running MacOS X 10.13.6 (High Sierra).
And I'm running Emacs v26.1, from [Emacs for MacOS X](https://emacsformacosx.com).

Comment: Maybe it's a mistake in that book? I don't see anything in the docstring suggesting the kill ring should be affected by that command.

Comment: the 2nd edition of that book us 22 years old, so there are bound to be things in there that are out of date

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by the comments, the book is out of date in this respect.

That command no longer *kills* the region; it just deletes it.

The change was released in GNU Emacs 19.34 (21-aug-96)

- Commit [a9a6f83ff3b4db87187e7f79f0a4e31d9663062a](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit?id=a9a6f83ff3b4db87187e7f79f0a4e31d9663062a)
- Commit [4e217e5069de0bfe49900b79f696f3feec9da6b9](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit?id=4e217e5069de0bfe49900b79f696f3feec9da6b9)